# How to use an Ant script to obtain the information from transfer log progress message in MQFTE?

Tags: ant

I am using the Ant scripts to perform several file transfer tasks in MQFTE.

I am trying to figure out how to get the information from the "transfer log progress" message.  Specifically, I need to retrieve the information in  element under  tag.

Does anyone has any Ant script examples that shows how to retrieve that information?